# How to get the suffix of a URI (after #)?

Tags: rdf, sparql

I typed this query:

```
SELECT ?p  FROM a.owl WHERE {<http:/edamontology.org/operation_0311> ?p ?o }
```

The result is the full  URI of each property. E.g.:

```
http:/www.geneontology.org/formats/oboInOwl#inSubset
http:/www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#subClassOf
http:/www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Class
```

I don't want the URI, I just want to have the part after #.  That is, I want

```
inSubset
subClassOf
Class
```

How can I get that?

Comment: In my program, I think I may create a method. For each URI, that method just return the string after #.

Comment: What if a property URI is used that doesn’t contain `#`? Do you want to have the last path segment then, separated by `/`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want the part of the string of the URI after an occurrence of #. That's easy enoug with [strafter](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-strafter).

```
select (strafter(str(?p),'#') as ?plabel) {
  values ?p { <http:/www.geneontology.org/formats/oboInOwl#inSubset>
              <http:/www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#subClassOf>
              <http:/www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Class> }
}
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=select%20%28strafter%28str%28%3Fp%29%2C%27%23%27%29%20as%20%3Fplabel%29%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20values%20%3Fp%20%7B%20%3Chttp%3A%2Fwww.geneontology.org%2Fformats%2FoboInOwl%23inSubset%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Chttp%3A%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23subClassOf%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Chttp%3A%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2002%2F07%2Fowl%23Class%3E%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=30000&debug=on)

```
plabel
----------
inSubset
subClassOf
Class
```